# How Can Make Android Flash Light in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am try to make Android Flash Light App is it possible to make React Native Language ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `react-native-torch`. It can be used to turn on-off the flaslight. More about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-torch).